# 112404: Exit code 1 error while deploying Spring App to Azure

Tags: azure-spring-cloud, azure-spring-boot

I have a simple Spring App. Nothing complicated about it.

It is trying to connect to a database that I have created previously on Azure.

This is my **application.properties** which points to the database (everything with the connection strings, passwords etc works fine)

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://shape-shop-db.mysql.database.azure.com:3306/shapeshop?useSSL=false&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true&serverTimezone=UTC&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false
spring.datasource.username=xxxxxxxx
spring.datasource.password=xxxxxxxx
```

When I try to deploy it using this command :

```
az spring app deploy --resource-group myResourceGroup --service myService --name myApp --artifact-path target/myJar-0.1.0.jar
```

then I get this error :

```
[1/3] Requesting for upload URL.
[2/3] Uploading package to blob.
[3/3] Updating deployment in app "shapeshop" (this operation can take a while to complete)
112404: Exit code 1: application error, please refer to https://aka.ms/exitcode
```

I can't find any details of what this 112404 error means. What would definately help me is if I could see some log files, but I am not sure how to find the logs.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

1. If you application is not a web application, you should disable probe like this:

> az spring app update 
> --resource-group xxx 
> --service xxx 
> --name xxx 
> --disable-probe true 
> --verbose

2. You can use Azure CLI to get logs:

> az spring app log tail 
> -n xxx 
> -s xxx 
> -g xxx 
> --subscription xxx 
> --lines 200

Refs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/spring-cloud/app/log?view=azure-cli-latest